# Netbeans, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

There is my following problem :

> ```
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.vecmath.Point3f
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:244)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
> Caused: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/vecmath/Point3f
> ```

I don't really understand why it can't find this class. I have the latest version of Java 1.7. Any ideas ?

Best regards.

Comment: Vecmath is not part of standard Java. You should download its jar separately and add it to your build.

Comment: Please delete the class files and then clean the project. Run the main class you may.If you have already added the jar file then you need to recompile jar and then replace new jar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Point3f` is part of the Java3D API, which is a separate download. [Read more here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-138252.html).

Cheers,

Comment: It was the problem, Java3D was not installed. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Maven, try to add this dependency please :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>java3d</groupId>
    <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, download the latest java3d library : https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html

After imported, update your imports in your Java class and it should be fine to compile.